# PHP Multidimensional Array By Specific Value

Tags: php

I have an array in multidimensional, which i want to get the array set only match my specific value, right now i have a column call related_users, I need a statement that will get this array values only when is this array's related_user value is 1.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [advertiser] => Hairvolution
        [postdate] => 
        [campaign_period] => 
        [related_users] => 1
        [reporting_period] => 
        [Delivered Impressions] => 1439763
        [Clicks] => 4124
        [Click-Through Rate] => 0.29
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [advertiser] => 
        [postdate] => 
        [campaign_period] => 
        [related_users] => 2
        [reporting_period] => 
        [Delivered Impressions] => 
        [Clicks] => 
        [Click-Through Rate] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [advertiser] => maxlibin
        [postdate] => 
        [campaign_period] => 
        [related_users] => 2
        [reporting_period] => 
        [Delivered Impressions] => 
        [Clicks] => 
        [Click-Through Rate] => 
    )
 [3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [advertiser] => maxlibin
        [postdate] => 
        [campaign_period] => 
        [related_users] => 1
        [reporting_period] => 
        [Delivered Impressions] => 
        [Clicks] => 
        [Click-Through Rate] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [advertiser] => maxlibin
        [postdate] => 
        [campaign_period] => 
        [related_users] => 1
        [reporting_period] => 
        [Delivered Impressions] => 
        [Clicks] => 
        [Click-Through Rate] => 
    )
}
```

Comment: Instead of saying "I need a statement", better tell us what you have tried.

Comment: Can you give an example of "i want to get the array set only match my specific value" ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` loop and iterate it and check the `related_users` value ,if it matches `1` then append the array to new array.

```
$arr = array();
for($i=0;$i< count($your_array);$i++) {
    if($your_array[$i]['related_users'] == 1) {
        $arr[] = $your_array[$i];
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, what you want, but you can try this code:

```
$final = array();
    foreach($arrayName as $arrayItem){
        if ($arrayItem['related_user'] == 1){
            $final[] = $arrayItem;
        }
    }
var_dump($final);
```

Answer (score 0):

use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for array that  easy way to iterate over arrays and check the `related_users` value ,if it is `1` then append to the new array `$result`.

```
$result = array();
foreach($your_array as $Item){
  if ($Item['related_user'] == 1){
     $result[] = $Item;
  }
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$rated = array();
foreach($yourArr as $arr) {
    if($arr['related_user'] == 1) {
        $rated[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
                $array=YourArray;
            $result=array();
            foreach($array as $a) {

                if($a['related_users']==1){
                    $result=$a;
                }

            }

            echo "Resultant Array =";
            echo "<pre>";
                print_r($result);
            echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function get_specific_arr_set($array) {

      $arr_final = array();
      if (!empty($array)) {

        foreach ($array as $item) {

            if ($item['related_users'] == 1) {

                $arr_final[] = $item; 
            }
        }
      }

      return $arr_final;
    }
```

`$result = get_specific_arr_set($your_arr);`

`echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";exit;`